# Redux option doensn't seem when include from functions.php

Tags: php, array

When I write redux framework option into header.php, it is shown.However when I add the same php code into a php file and include the php file from functions.php, it doesn't seem.

header.php:

```
<?php global $redux_demo; ?>
<?php echo wp_kses_post( $redux_demo['text-call-header'] );
?>
```

function.php :

```
include ( get_template_directory() . '/theme-color.php' );
```

theme-color.php contains same code above also global redux variable but it doesn't give any output.

why?

as a smiliar second question, also I can't get output from my custom plugin when I include theme-color.php from my custom plugin.

Comment: Where in functions.php have you included this file? If it's not inside a hook then I would wager that `$redux_demo` hasn't been defined yet. Normally you wouldn't echo a value directly from functions.php, so this is not a good way to test whatever you're testing. You should include the file inside a function that runs later.

Comment: yes, I solved it

Answer (score 0):

```
function theme_color() {
    include ( get_template_directory() . '/theme-color.php' );
}
add_action('wp_head','theme_color');
```

so it will be loaded in head